# Can HDSDR perform the work of Direwolf?

Tags: digital-modes, modes, software-defined-radio, baofeng, software

I have a setup in which [Direwolf](https://github.com/wb2osz/direwolf) is used in conjunction with a Baofeng radio to basically send data (AFSK). My app connects to the TCP server provided by Direwolf, send him some data which then is forwarded to the PC speaker. The PC speaker is connected to the Baofeng MIC and so it works.

Would it be possible to replace Direwolf by HDSDR? So HDSDR forwards the data to the Baofeng radio?

May I provide more information?

Answer (score 1):

No, HDSDR is only compatible with software defined radios, not standard transceivers like a Baofeng. There are a few SDRs that are made to connect to the sound card, but most connect via USB. If you want to experiment without spending much, try one of the common RTL-SDR USB dongles, though those are receive-only. SDRs which are capable of transmitting are fairly expensive.